# TikZ: a point on the ray

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent for ([nodesep=10pt]{B}A) in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/what-is-the-equivalent-for-nodesep-10ptba-in-tikz)

Consider a ray `[AB)`, where `A` and `B` are `\coordinate`s in TikZ. One wants to select a point `M` on this ray such that `|AM| = d`, where `d` is some given number. The easisest way to do this?

Comment: `($(A)!d cm!(B)$)` with calc library