# Drawing rays in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to draw rays using TikZ? By ray I mean a line that has a defined starting point but no defined end. So I would like to draw a straight line, that starts at point A, crosses point B and has a lenght of l. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent for (\[nodesep=10pt\]{B}A) in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/what-is-the-equivalent-for-nodesep-10ptba-in-tikz)

Comment: @PGFTricks I do agree, that the answer to my question can be found in the mentioned post, but the question is not found there. As someone who never used PSTricks, I have no idea what `([nodesep=10pt]{B}A)` means. Before posting this question I searched the forum for a possible answer and was not able to find it. Therefore I would not call this a duplicate, as the intentions of the two questions are quite different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library syntax for this: `\draw (A) -- ($(A)!5cm!(B)$);` draws a line starting at `A` going in the direction from `A` to `B` for a distance of 5cm:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, minimum size=1pt, inner sep=1pt, fill}]
\node (A) [label=above:A] {};
\node (B) at (2,-1) [label=above:B] {};

\draw (A) -- ($(A)!5cm!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks.

```
    \psline(A)([nodesep=3]{B}A)
```

draws a line from `A` to a point that is 3 unit away from `A` and on the fictitious line `AB` (or its extension).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=90](3,3){A}(4,2){B}
    \pscircle[linecolor=gray](A){3}
    \psline(A)([nodesep=3]{B}A)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea for demonstration with the circle.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Although I was asking for TikZ, this may be helpful for people serching the forum for a PSTricks answer.