# What is the TikZ equivalent for ([offset=2]{A}B)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Based on the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78125/19356), `($(A)!1cm!(B)$)` in TikZ is equivalent to `([nodesep=1]{B}A)` in PSTricks. It is just about the "radial" distance specified by two points. How about the "transverse" distance specified by two points?

More precisely, in PSTricks, the syntax `([offset=2]{A}B)` represents a  new point (namely `C`) which is 2 unit apart from the line joining `A` and `B` such that `BC` is perpendicular to `AB`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(4,5){B}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](A)(B)
    \pstGeonode([offset=2]{A}B){C}
    \psline[linecolor=blue](B)(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the TikZ equivalent for such a syntax?

### Miscellaneous

`([offset=2]{A}B)` can also be written as `([nodesep=2,angle=90]{A}B)`. Other approaches are also possible with, for example, transformations provided by `pst-eucl`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent syntax is `($(B)!2cm!90:(A)$)`, which is the point `2cm` away from `B` on the line from `B` to `A` after that line has been rotated by 90 degrees.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);

\coordinate (C) at ($(B)!2cm!90:(A)$);
\node at (A) [above] {A};
\node at (B) [above] {B};
\node at (C) [above] {C};

\fill (A) circle [radius=2pt] (B) circle [radius=2pt] (C) circle [radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `tkz-euclide` package, using syntax `\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed, K=2](B,A) \tkzGetPoint {C}` define a point `C` from `B`  perpendicular to `AB` with 2cm length.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit
 \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 5/5/K}
  \tkzDefPoints{1/1/A, 4/4/B}  
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](A)
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](B) 
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,B)
  \tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed, K=2](B,A) \tkzGetPoint {C}   
  \tkzDrawLine[color=blue,add=0 and 0](B,tkzPointResult)
 \tkzDrawSegment(O,K)
 \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)
   \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](C)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]